# Minor Edits to Class File inside JAR

Tags: java, vim, jar

I have a custom legacy application built in Java that I need to make a very minor edit to. I need to change a reference to Year of Week 'YYYY' to Year of Day 'yyyy' in one class file.

I found out that vim can edit the class files within JARs which seemed the easiest solution, so using that to make the edit a copy of the JAR. However, when trying to run the new JAR I am hitting exceptions  for the class I edited stating:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Extra bytes at the end of class"
```

Looking at the file sizes, it looks like even though all I did was change 'YYYY' to 'yyyy' on one line, the file is 52 bytes larger than the original. I think vim is adding extra characters when it saves. I tried 'set nofixendol', 'set binary noeol', 'set binary noendofline' before saving since I saw people mentioning vim adding endoflines, but it hasn't helped.

It's such a minor change in a huge bundle of custom code, but I can't seem to actually make the change.

Previously tried to compile from source or from decompiling the JAR, but always failed due to dependency issues, no idea how it was originally compiled. Tried including the original JAR when compiling and it still didn't work. That's why I was so hopeful when I found vim could edit it.

Any ideas on what's going wrong with vim editing or other ways of making the minor change to this app would be appreciative. Losing my mind a bit here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a hex editor (if you're using Linux, `hexedit` should be available in command line) to edit binary files. Text editors usually adds something to the content or convert characters.

Oh, and if you want to make more complex changes [JBE](http://set.ee/jbe/) is pretty cool.